# Basic topology question: proving int(A) is contained in A and A is contained in the closure of A

Tags: general-topology

I tried to prove $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq A \subseteq \overline{A}$ for a subset A of a topological space X.
Even though it seems really simple i can't go further than the definition of $\operatorname{int}(A)$.

If anyone would like to help i would really appreciate it.

Comment: What is your definition of $int(A)$?

Comment: Try to use the LaTeX commands `\text{int}, \subseteq, \overline{A}` to write $\text{int}\,,\,\subseteq\,,\,\overline{A}$

Comment: You need to give your definitions. One standard definition of interior and closure are the largest open set contained in $A$ and the smallest closed set containing $A$, respectively.

Comment: trying to prove the following: \text{int}(A) \subseteq A \subseteq \overline{A}

Comment: Also add the definition of $\overline{A}$ as well.

Comment: \text{int}\ (A) is defined as the union of all open sets contained in X and the closure of A is defined as the intersection of closed sets contained in X. I am sorry but I can not use the commands this is my first time and I am trying to learn. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, $\operatorname{int}(A) = \cup \{O : O \text { open }, O \subseteq A \}$. Then clearly, if $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$, then there is some open $O$ such that $x \in O$ and $O \subseteq A$. So clearly $x \in A$.

$\overline{A} = \cap \{C : C \text{ closed}, A \subseteq C \}$.

Then pick $x \in A$, and let $C$ be any closed set that contains $A$.
Then $x \in C$. As $C$ is an arbitrary member of the sets we take the intersection of, $x \in \cap \{C : C \text{ closed}, A \subseteq C \} = \overline{A}$. So $A \subseteq \overline{A}$.